# Logout system in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, logout

I want to logout with defualt system

I visit :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/

Can you show me a project or a code for logout in defualt system?

Code or project in **github** or **stackoverflow**

**note : **i want to know :

what it return ?

What i need?

It will destroye session?

It will unset session?

Or waht?

All **answers** will help me

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout

Comment: I write in my question i vistited this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

This answer might help:
[Why can't I logout on django user auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348025/why-cant-i-logout-on-django-user-auth)